# Broken while-loop on evaluation of azure commands in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, azure

I have a csv file, params.csv, consisting of the following dummy data for instance:

```
"Victor Okwuemu","n939NekyPa8910","VictorO003_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
"Jackson Kiraly","n939Nek00O1yPa","JacksonK004_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
"Benson Thomas","n939Nek025yPa","bensonT005_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
```

I used a while loop to read each line and extract the strings in each line based on the comma into the variables: `displayname`, `password` and `upn` using these commands: `$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1)`, `$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 2)` and `$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 3)` respectively as shown below:

```bash
file='params.csv'
while read line; do
  displayName=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1)
  password=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 2)
  upn=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 3)
  var1="az ad user create --display-name"
  var2="--password"
  var3="--user-principal-name"
  eval ${var1} ${displayName} ${var2} ${password} ${var3} ${upn}
done < $file
```

My goal is to pass the extracted strings into an Azure Active Directory CLI commands to create multiple users in Azure Active Directory tenant without using Azure portal.

The program loops, evaluates the first line and adds the user to my Azure active directory tenant, then fails to do for other lines in the the file.
However, when I comment out the 'eval' line and echo the variables, the while loop goes through every line and and extracts all the strings for each line.

I have tried writing the commands in various other format as follows:

```
az ad user create --display-name "$displayName" --password "$password" --user-principal-name "$upn"
```

```
echo "az ad user create --display-name $displayName --password $password --user-principal-name $upn"
```

```
az ad user create --display-name $(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1 | tr -d '"') --password $(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 2 | tr -d '"') --user-principal-name $(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 3 | tr -d '"')
```

All of these methods have failed to create the users as I expected. Any body with an idea on this? The problem here is that the while loop breaks after evaluating the first line in the file.

Comment: @markp-fuso I thought so which is why I tried trimming out the double quotes with this other command: az ad user create --display-name $(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1 | tr -d '"') --password $(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 2 | tr -d '"') --user-principal-name $(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 3 | tr -d '"')

Comment: I'm not familiar with `az` so not sure how it handles arguments with embedded spaces (eg, names must be inside quotes or does it take all unquoted strings between `--display-name` and `--password` as the display name?); I'm surprised the first altnerative doesn't work (`az ad user create --display-name "$displayName" ...`) as that's how I'd probably write the script ... so that leads me to wonder if there's something in the actual input file that we're not seeing in the sample provided here ...  what is generated if you add `typeset -p displayName password upn` at end of loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we should avoid using `eval` as much as possible due to its vulnerability,
would you please try instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="params.csv"
cmd=("az" "ad" "user" "create" "--display-name")
var2="--password"
var3="--user-principal-name"

while IFS=, read -r displayName password upn; do
    "${cmd[@]}" "$displayName" "$var2" "$password" "$var3" "$upn"
done < <(tr -d '"' < "$file")
```

- You don't need to repead `cut` command to split the lines.
  `read` builtin does it for you by assigning `IFS` to the delimiting
  character.
- The command line arguments can be put in an array, not in the
  single string.
- The surrounding double quotes are removed by the `tr` command,
  assuming double quotes are not embedded *within* the strings.

Btw your 1st trial `az ad user create --display-name "$displayName" ..` fails
because the variables keeps the surrounding double quotes then the command
line is equivalent to something like
`az ad user create --display-name "\"Victor Okwuemu\"" ..`.

As a side note, the `echo` command is often used to validate the command line while debugging,
but please keep in mind that `echo` sometimes deceives us especially
about the quotings. Even if the output of `echo` looks good, it does not
mean the arguments are correctly passed to the command.
An alternative  is to write a test command such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

which prints the passed arguments line by line.
Try to replace the command `az` with `./testcommand` above, run, and examine
the output whether the arguments are properly passed.

**[Edit]**
As a part of debugging, would you execute a script with the following commands:

```
az ad user create --display-name "Victor Okwuemu" --password "n939NekyPa8910" --user-principal-name "VictorO003_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
az ad user create --display-name "Jackson Kiraly" --password "n939Nek00O1yPa" --user-principal-name "JacksonK004_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
az ad user create --display-name "Benson Thomas" --password "n939Nek025yPa" --user-principal-name "bensonT005_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
```

**[Edit2]**
Would you please try the following for the test purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=("az" "ad" "user" "create" "--display-name")
var2="--password"
var3="--user-principal-name"

while IFS=, read -r displayName password upn; do
    "${cmd[@]}" "$displayName" "$var2" "$password" "$var3" "$upn"
done < <(tr -d '"' <<EOS
"Victor Okwuemu","n939NekyPa8910","VictorO003_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
"Jackson Kiraly","n939Nek00O1yPa","JacksonK004_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
"Benson Thomas","n939Nek025yPa","bensonT005_gmail.com#EXT#@Hegemongroup.onmicrosoft.com"
EOS
)
```

**[Edit3]**
Would you please try the following script to generate another script
`newscript.sh` which should be identical to the script in `[Edit]`:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="params.csv"
cmd=("az" "ad" "user" "create" "--display-name")
var2="--password"
var3="--user-principal-name"

{
    echo "#!/bin/bash"
    echo
    while IFS=, read -r displayName password upn; do
        echo "${cmd[@]}" "\"$displayName\"" "$var2" "\"$password\"" "$var3" "\"$upn\""
    done < <(tr -d '"' < "$file")
} > newscript.sh
```

Then run the generated script.

**[Edit4]**
Here is a variant of `[Edit3]` without generating a separate script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="params.csv"
cmd=("./az" "ad" "user" "create" "--display-name")
var2="--password"
var3="--user-principal-name"

while IFS=, read -r displayName password upn; do
    echo "${cmd[@]}" "\"$displayName\"" "$var2" "\"$password\"" "$var3" "\"$upn\""
done < <(tr -d '"' < "$file") | bash -
```

- The final pipeline `| bash -` feeds the output of previous processings
  (or generated `az` command lines) directly to `bash` instead of
  generating a script file.
- The double quotes in the command line may be tricky. The outermost double
  quotes for each variable are removed by `echo` and the inner ones
  (escaped with backslashes) are removed when passed to the `az` command.
  Try to replace the command `az` with `./testcommand` and see the output as I have noted in the first answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your contribution. However, I have tried your approach, the read command did its job perfectly well by looping through to the end like in my own case, but the loop gets broken after the first line is evaluated. The issue I had before.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.I feel sorry I cannot be a help so far.
I'm beginning to think Asure command may be causing the problem.
Does it produce some error message or silently fail?
What if you modify the script to execute three literal `az` commands
in sequence expanding the parameters in the file without using the `while` loop?

Comment: okay, I also think the problem maybe coming from Azure commands. However, I don't get what you meant by three literal az commands. Can you please give me an example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: As it is not easy to express in the comment here, I've updated my answer as `[Edit]` with the commands. Would you please test it? BR.

Comment: The az commands in your edit section works really well. The members were successfully created. However, when combined with a loop, the az command fails. What could be responsible for this?

Comment: Thank you for testing the code. The good news is `Azure` is doing a good job.
Another possibility is the `params.csv` file may be broken with some unprintable
special character(s). Please try 1) to change the order of lines and see if
it also fails after the first line. 2) to re-edit the file hopefully with another text
editor. Linux-oriented editors would be preferable. BR.

Comment: Hello Tshiono, the params.csv file was edited in nano. I will try to re-order the lines to see the outcome.

Comment: Hello Tshiono, I re-ordered the lines, but the loop still got broken

Comment: Thank you for testing. I have asked you this before but does it produce some error message or silently fail?

Comment: What about putting `--debug` option and/or `--verbose` option to the `az` commans?

Comment: Hello Tshiono, it silently failed. It did not put out any error. It just added the first member on the line, printed it to the screen and then exited.

Comment: I will try adding the options you suggested to the az command to see what comes out of it. I'll get back to you once it's done.

Comment: Hi Tshiono, I added --verbose to the az command and it brought up info about data on just the first line

Comment: Thank you for your patience.
It looks the loop terminates before executing the 2nd `az` command.
Then would you please test the script added in the **[Edit2]** section in my answer?
It uses the `here document` instead of the csv file to isolate the possible problem.
The `--verbose` option may be or may not be added. BR.

Comment: Okay, I will try that and get back to you ASAP

Comment: Hi tshiono, I run the code as given in the Edit2. It returned the same single member. The loop breaks after the first line.

Comment: As the script in `[Edit2]` issues the *identical* az commands which is
executed the sript in `[Edit]`, I have no idea what is going on there.
Then, as a workaround, would you please try the script in `[Edit3]`,
which generates a separate script `newscript.sh`. Then run the generated
script. BR.

Comment: Hello tshiono. I tried the edit 3 commands, it did not work at all. Nothing was printed to the screen neither were the members added to my Azure Active Directory tenant. It checks out to my shell when I execute the script.

Comment: Would you compare the generated script `newscript.sh` with the one in `[Edit]` which has been proven to work? Use `diff` command or `cmp` command to compare them. They are expected to be identical (possibly except for the 1st shebang line). In my test environment they are absolutely identical.

Comment: Wow, it worked at last. The new script run and the members were created. However, there is a catch. What if you need to deploy the script in a pipeline at a given time of the day to different environments? That is you want to automate things. That means I'll have to be around all the time to add execute permissions to the new file to be able to create the members in a new environment. I am considering a scenario where someone with administrator role creates new members every time of the day in my tenant, and for security reasons, I want to bulk delete my users at the close of work and replace

Comment: my user list with my original list at the end of work in a pipeline. How can I deal with this scenario?

Comment: Hello tshiono. Don't worry about it, I figured out how to do it. I just need to add  chmod +x newscript.sh
./newscript.sh to the end of the script and that settles it.

Comment: Thank you so much tshiono. That was quite ingenious. Could you please explain this part of the command : echo "${cmd[@]}" "\"$displayName\"" "$var2" "\"$password\"" "$var3" "\"$upn\"" ; the backward slashes and the double quotes again even though we are trimming the double quotes from the varibles' values

Comment: It is a good news it is working now, although I don't know what has changed
on your side. As for the generated script, your idea to add
`chmod +x newscript.sh; ./newscript.sh` is nice.
I have added `[Edit4]` which does not generate a separate script
just for reference with some explanations answering your last question.

Comment: If you feel my answer solves your problem, I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by
clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.

Comment: okay, great. I will try edit 4 also and see

Comment: Hello tshiono, what check mark are you referring to beside the answer?